# powershell new-item with -value and sub parameter

Tags: powershell

I want to aliasing the following command:

```
new-item -path alias:rmn  -value "Enter-PSSession -ComputerName NUC"
```

What must be done that this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats not what aliases are for in powershell. you need to créate a function for that:

```
function rmn {
    Enter-PSSession -ComputerName NUC
}
```

Aliases are only for commands, you cannot use parameters with aliases

alternatively you can créate alias rmn for `enter-pssession` and use it like so:

```
rmn -computername nuc
```